# Fetching connection string from appconfig file in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I have the following connection string declared in my `app.config` file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User Id=xx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I try to fetch this connection string using the following C# code snippet, I get the value `null`. I am not able to obtain the connection string. Is there anything wrong in the syntax?

First attempt:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"];
string result = settings.ConnectionString;
```

Second attempt:

```
string result = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"];
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a file deployed next to the assembly you're running that is called `MyApp.exe.config`, and that contains that connection string?  Are you using NUnit?  NUnit seems to need the app.config in a different spot than normal when running it from VS.  If you're using an asp.net web project, you'll probably need your connection string in a `web.config` file, not an app.config file...

Comment: The first syntax would be the correct one to fetch the value from the `<connectionStrings>` section. The second will definitely not work.

Comment: No its not a web project , its plane c# project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a non-web project, and with app.config set up as in the OP here's what I usually do, since the config file changes names when the app is compiled (to yourapp.exe.config):

```
    public static Configuration ExeConfig()
    {
        Assembly service = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourClass));
        return ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(service.Location);
    }
```

Then to reference the s'th connection string:

```
ExeConfig().ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[s].ConnectionString
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want this to be the name of the initial assembly if you had this in a library or something, and so then it seems that'd you'd want to use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()

Comment: You can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() instead Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(YourClass)) - YourClass is confusing (whitch class?).

Answer (score 10):

First, you must add the `appSettings` tag

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add name="SqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User Id=xx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </appSettings>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Second, add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project and insert a `using System.Configuration` in the source.

Then, you can use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to access your config setting:

```
string result = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"];
```

Comment: This is the only way I could find to get the settings in a .Net 4.5 Console App

Comment: I am trying this in Visual Studio 2008 and getting error that "ConnectionString has invalid child element "appSettings"

Comment: Obsolete method.. Use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"] instead. Note: connection must be directly in appSettings section (not ideal for some reasons).

Answer (score 2):

Am having the same problem but after much research, i discovered that the reason why the code is throwing a null reference exception is because if you use the connectionString name, it will return null and when you try to call a the **ToString()** or the ConnectionString property of the **ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings** property that's when the exception is thrown, so to
return the correct connection string, you have to index into the ConnectionStringSettings using the following code.

```
ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[/* index */];

string conString = conSettings.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this to get my connect string "OracleDbContext"...

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDbContext"].ConnectionString;
```

my web.config looks like:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" 
         providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
         connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;              
                           Password=oracle_user_password;
                           Data Source=oracle" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed when compiling WinForm App in VS 2013:

I add connection strings my Settings File - which updates my app.config file

When I would expect:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["theConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

I have to write:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyAppNameSpace.Properties.Settings.theConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Everything else is business as usual

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="ConnectionString" value="blah blah blah"/>  </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Will the above configuration works with the API/code like:

```
string str = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SqlConnectionString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first syntax is definitely valid.

The possible cause is that the configuration file is not loaded properly in the application. I want to ensure what type of project it is. If it is a WinForm application or Console application, you need set the  in the app.config. It will be compiled to .config and loaded when the application is launched. If it is a Web application, I'm afraid you cannot add the  node to app.config, since it will not be loaded. You need to put it in the web.config. In addition, if you want to put the settings in the config file with a .net library (DLL), the configuration file will not be loaded anyway. The configuration file will only follow the main application.

Comment: How do you find out this error? If you are debugging the code in VS, please confirm that the <appName>.vshost.exe.config does exist. VS debug will use this configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

One other possible cause of failure could be incorrect name resolution by the .NET framework.

If the application name is longer than the 8.3 name (for instance `GreatStuff.exe`) it might get launched using its short 8.3 equivalent name (in my example `GREATS~1.EXE`) and .NET will then look for the `app.config` file by simply appending `.config` to the short name. And this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Based on Merlyn Morgan-Graham and Edward Zhu comments, I rebuilt my project, which used the app.config to create a myapp.exe.config file with the connection string. Original first syntax then worked.

Other problem: Tried using the project properties dialog to modify the connection string and it added "project.My.Mysettings. to the connection string name. Which caused failure.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to do this for console app:

```
    <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SqlConString" value="some connection string"/>
  </appSettings>
```

to read it

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and then use

```
string CONSTRING;
AppSettingsReader ap = new AppSettingsReader();
CONSTRING = ap.GetValue("SqlConString",typeof(string)).ToString();
```