# Get ConnectionString from app.config in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have defined my connection String in app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="CString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=Bilal-PC;Initial Catalog=ATMSoftware;Integrated Security=False; User Id=sa; Password=123" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to get it into my C# class and I have tried all the [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612560/fetching-connection-string-from-appconfig-file-in-c-sharp). but I am getting an error on configuration manager.

Please help me.

Comment: BTW, what's the error message you're getting??

Comment: what error and please show the code where the error occurs

Comment: are you using win forms or web forms? also please detail what error you are getting

Comment: The ConfigurationManager not exist in this context?

Comment: You need to read up on namespaces and the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you have added a reference to System.Configuration in your project, and place a

```
using System.Configuration;
```

statement at the top of your source. The `ConfigurationManager` type should now be available.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: By using System.Configuration; it is not available

Comment: The question is tagged [homework] - when that happens, we try to give answers that teach, not a complete solution.

Comment: I'll leave teaching as the reward for the inquistive mind.

Comment: Bilal, have you added the System.Configuration assembly as a reference to your project? In Visual Studio, right click References, Add Reference, .NET, System.Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx) for more information

```
var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"];
string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: The question is tagged [homework] - when that happens, we try to give answers that _teach_, not a complete solution.

Comment: The ConfigurationManager not exist in this context?