# Possible reasons why SqlConnection is NULL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net

Using Visual Studio 2012 which was recently installed but now I can't connect to our SQL Server database.

These are the steps I'm following

1. create `App1.config`
2. type this in `App1.config`:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name ="xxx" connectionString="USER ID=xx;PASSWORD=xx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;Data Source=xx;Initial Catalog=xx" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
   ```
3. Add a reference to the project to `System.Configuration`
4. Create access to namespaces via:

   ```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
   ```
5. implement the following:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Configuration;

   namespace ConsoleApplication10 {
       class Program {
           static void Main(string[] args) {

               SqlConnection conn = null;
               conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString);

           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. I've created a new console app and added the above and I still get an error `NullReferenceException was unhandled` `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` ...

[image]

**EDIT**

Via the immediate window I determined that the following is null:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString
```

If I hard-code the connection string into the constructor for `SqlConnection` then it connects ok

What am I missing - something really obvious!! Or is this in connection with my new VS ?

Comment: Determine exactly which variable/expression was null by using the debugger.

Comment: What's null? `conn` or the connection string returned by the `ConfigurationManager`?

Comment: poor format, review you question. some parts are missing

Comment: @Cybermaxs ok - I'll determine exactly what is null and add to the OP

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - thanks : looks like the configuration manager is returning a null string - if I hard-code the string in then it executes fine

Comment: are you sure of the xxx ?

Comment: @tschmit007 you can see the xml I have in my OP - it just says `<add name ="IMS" connectionString="...`

Comment: @tschmit007 I'm pretty sure that he just put in the `xxx` to abbreviate the longer connection string name...

Comment: @whytheq: Added this as an answer.

Comment: yes I quite sure also... my question is: are you sure of the coherence of the name and the litteral string. What is the result of Console.Writeline(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count).

Comment: @tschmit007 - let me try

Comment: @tschmit007 it is returning 1

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: great and if you try to connect (or writeline) with ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString ? And by the way WriteLine ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name.

Comment: @tschmit007 it comes up with some random connectio0n string that I've not named!! `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI...` ; I'm using full SQL-Server 2008 R2 !

Comment: @whytheq then you have to check the properties of your app1.config and/or of your application in VS. This connection string should come from machine.config or elsewhere. The response of tomfanning seems to be the right one to investigate.

Comment: @tschmit007 - how do I check the properties of my app1.config in VS ?

Comment: How about opening up the project properties, switching to the `Settings` tab and checking which connection strings are there? You should not edit the `app.config` file directly.

Comment: @tschmit007 - ok : thanks for your help - fixed now; jot down your comments as an answer as they really helped.

Comment: @whytheq please share the solution

Comment: See my answer here for [app.config][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612560/fetching-connection-string-from-appconfig-file-in-c-sharp/32036555#32036555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check what is in the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings by excecuting at least the following:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings != null ) {
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
    Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].Name);
    ....
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("null");
}
```

This will highlight any obvious problems like duplication of the `App.config` file which could well be the case as you mentioned `App1.config` in the `OP`.

Comment: +1 thanks for all the help - a frustrating question but if you feel kind you might like to cancel out some of the downvotes it seems to be gathering!

Comment: @whytheq I think downvote came from formatting more than from relevance of the question.

Comment: formatting looks fine - I've fully explained the problem with all code and screenshots...just edited your answer with my embarrassing finding!

Comment: You missed `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`

Comment: @JohnSaunders no - I added a configuration file to the solution and there was already one in there; so even though I was using the correct name I think the project was referring to the original config file. Once I deleted one of them and renamed to App.config rather than App1.config all was well in the World again !

Comment: ... and then did a build. App.config becomes executableName.exe.config, which is where the real settings are.

Comment: @tschmit007: I meant you should also check if `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is null.

Answer (score 3):

Check your output folder.

Assuming your application is called `myapp.exe`, there should be `myapp.exe.config`.

This should exist, and should contain the contents of your `app.config` file in Visual Studio.

If it doesn't, check whether you already have an `app.config` file elsewhere (I notice you called your file `app1.config`)

Comment: Even if it doesn't exist, the default values will be used.

Comment: +1 thanks tom - exactly as you noticed app**1**.config was the problem. I thought this was a relevent question but already on -2 !

Answer (score 2):

Have your tried checking what the value of ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString is and hardcoding with that value? Do you still get null?

Also it's advised to created the connection like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString))
{
        //code        
}
```

I would reply but I don't have enough rep yet ... :-(

Comment: let me try with it hard-coded ; can determine if it is the connection reference causing the problem then

Answer (score 2):

Guessing from the fact that your code does not "do anything" with `conn` yet, I'm pretty sure that the `ConfigurationManager` returns `null` for the connection string name you pass in. An exception is thrown by the `SqlConnection`'s constructor when passing in `null` instead of a valid connection string.

Comment: if I add code so that my code does something - like run a stored procedure than it still errors on this line of code

Comment: Yes of course! I meant: As you are not using `conn` in the source code you posted in your question, the only thing that **can** be `null` is the result of the `ConfigurationManager` call. Had there been other code actually **using** `conn`, `conn` could also have been `null`, causing the exception. But that isn't the case, so the exception **must** come from `SqlCommand`s constructor.

Comment: +1 thanks for help (although I could almost see the smoke coming out of your ears!!) seems like I had duplicate app files in the solution!

Comment: I know: I could punch myself in the face!...can i edit them _not_ manually? ...via the properties section in the solution?

Comment: Yes, the connection string is a setting.

Comment: where do I find this setting in Visual Studio ...as someone with no xml knowledge I think it'd be safer if I found another way of setting someof this information

Comment: Double click "Properties" in your solution explorer for the project, then, in the Project Properties, select the "Settings" tab. There are all the program settings. Connection strings are just a setting of type "Connection String".

Answer (score 0):

When you place your connection strings in Properties->Settings, as a connection string, access them with full namespace, and your done.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612560/fetching-connection-string-from-appconfig-file-in-c-sharp/32036555#32036555)