# C# ConfigurationManager retrieves wrong connection string from app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, app-config

I have a simple WinForms app that will eventually be a game. Right now, I'm just working on the data access layer of it and I've run into a snag. I created a separate project called `DataAccess` and inside of that, I created a local `.mdf` SQL Server database file. I also created an `app.config` file to store the connections string.

Here's that config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TBG_Master"
             connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\TBG_Master.mdf"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

To retrieve the connection string from the app.config file I am using code pulled from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612560/fetching-connection-string-from-appconfig-file-in-c-sharp) question.

```
Assembly service = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
ConnectionStringsSection css = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(service.Location).ConnectionStrings;
string cs = css.ConnectionStrings["TBG_Master"].ConnectionString;
return cs;
```

When it gets to the line where it pulls the connection string using the string as the key, it gives me a null reference exception. After examining the `css.ConnectionString` collection, the only connection string it has in it looks like this:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

This is clearly not what it is in my `app.config` file, and I know there is no other `app.config` file in my `DataAccess` project. Also after debugging, I know for a fact that it is looking in the right assembly.

Why is it giving me this connection string and not the correct one?

Comment: The connection string needs to exist in the project *that executes*, not library projects:  e.g. it needs to be in your Winforms project's app.config.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh well then, that makes sense. Ill change my code and report back if it works :)

Comment: app.configs in libraries are for reference, or for compile-time tools.  But during runtime, only the executing project's app.config counts.

Comment: How get ONLY connecttionstrings from app.config/web.config, NOT machine.config?

In the machine.config is a connection string that is called "LocalSqlServer"; the default provider (as expected) is "System.Data.SqlClient", and the connection string is `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Amy pointed out, the reason this was not working was because the connection string was not stored in the executing assemblies app.config file. After moving it, it now works as it should. Thank you for the quick help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the machine.config file to hold connection strings that are independent of any application for a given machine. That way they don't have to be in any app.config file, because all applications automatically read the machine.config file on the machine they are executing on.